# XACML Policy and Request

Tags: xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

first I would like to mention that this certainly a novice question, but I was looking for hours now and I do not have an answer.

I just started trying XACML for academic purposes. I use the editor provided with wso2-is to write some policies and to evaluate them against some requests.

I created this policy to express that the subject **u** can **read or write** from a resource **d**

```
     <Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="test-bis" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target/>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="read-or-write">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">d</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
               <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny"/>
</Policy>
```

While matching to this simple request "Can **u** **read** from **d**" I got not applicable as result !
Here is the request:

```
 <Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">d</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

Anyone can help me on understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting "Not Applicable" it seems that your policy is either not enabled in WSO2 IS or not promoted to PDP for testing. Just check if the policy is enabled and promoted to PDP for test. You may also test the policy without promoting to PDP but in both the cases it should be in enabled mode.

I tried your policy in WSo2 IS 4.0.0 and its giving "Deny". And yes as David mentioned its because your policy combining algorithm is "deny-overrides" which is always getting "Deny" as per your default rule as below:

```
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny"/>
```

So either you need to make your policy combining algorithm as "permit-overrides" or drop the last rule.

Comment: Hi Yusuf, thanks for your help. I was not convinced for the need to enable the policy to try it in WSO2 IS, so I just restarted the server and I'm getting deny now. For the deny I will explain my concerns in a separate reply.

Comment: Actually, don't use permit-overrides. Use first-applicable. If you do Permit-overrides and the Deny-rule does trigger, then you would wrongly get Permit.

Comment: Also, adding Permit-overrides boils down to dropping the last rule.

Comment: Thanks both of you. The problem was fixed by keeping the fall through rule to deny and by changing the combining algoriethm to first-applicable.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the policy and the request you sent in the [Axiomatics Policy Server](https://www.axiomatics.com/axiomatics-policy-server.html) (disclaimer: I work for Axiomatics). The answer should in fact be `Deny`. Both rules triggered. You combined the rules inside a policy with a `deny-overrides` combining algorithm which means that `Deny` wins over `Permit`.

You can see below a screenshot of the policy simulation in APS which shows both rules being triggered and the second rule winning over the first one.

[image: Simulation trace in the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

If you are interested in understanding combining algorithms better, here's the "truth table" for `deny-overrides`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks David for these clarifications and the table for the algorithms. I understand things better now. BTW, since you are working for axiomatics, could you please tell me how to get the   free ALFA Plugin for Eclipse? (I registered since March 21 and wainting for the download link :-))

Comment: Sending it your way :-)

Comment: We have ALFA tutorials on YouTube:  We have tutorials on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czFBYGyHVdg&list=PL3tEmaACR8u1yK-I1RJuilJOw6wBQFnSp

Answer (score 0):

Yuor Request is fine and here's the Policy for your Reqirement.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="9f654de2-06d3-45c9-bb7f-947c9a9b247a" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
<Target>
<AnyOf>
<AllOf>
<Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">d</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:root-resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Match>
</AllOf>
</AnyOf>
</Target>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_write">
<Condition>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Apply>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue>
</Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Apply>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_read">
<Condition>
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue></Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Apply><Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue></Apply>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
</Apply>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
<Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule_Deny_All"/>
</Policy>
```

Comment: The policy did not work with WSO2 IS, I will have a closer look on it tonight. However I think the problem comes from my request: I think we can not define two actions for a same access request (I will create a seperate SO question for that).

Comment: did you publish the policy in wso2IS?

Comment: Yes, and I'm getting: 
`<Result>
<Decision>Indeterminate</Decision>
<Status>
<StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:processing-error"/>
<StatusMessage>Couldn't find AttributeDesignator attribute</StatusMessage>
</Status>
</Result>`

Comment: It means the wso2is policy finder may not able to get this policy