# Send several simultaneous actions in one XACML request

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

Can we specify two actions in a same XACML request?

This question comes from the following example. I want to do the following:

1. Define a policy like: U can use READ OR WRITE functions from a resource D (example of policy is available at [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372068/xacml-policy-and-request)
2. Define a request like: U wants to use READ AND DELETE (or any other not permitted actions)
3. Get as response: deny

So here is the request:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
 <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
 </Attributes>
 <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
 </Attributes>
 <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
  <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
   <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">d</AttributeValue>
  </Attribute>
 </Attributes>
</Request>
```

So again the question, can we have such XACML request (i.e. U asks from read and delete at the same time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. you can send two attribute values. But i guess, this would result `Permit`, as your policy has been written with `string-at-least-one-member-of` function. This function just verify whether there are at least one match.  As `read` action is matched,  Policy returns with `Permit`.  I guess,  you can use `subset` function to achieve this.  Please see following policy.. This would work for your requirement.

`<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="test-bis" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
   <Target></Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="read-or-write">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">d</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-subset">
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
               <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
               </Apply>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
               <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"></Function>
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">u</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny"></Rule>
</Policy>`